# How to call original class method using a object which is masked by Java root class i.e., Object class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have List of Lists of type Object which holds the objects of the NormalDistribution and BinomialDistribution classes of org.apache.commons.math3 library. Now i want to call sample() method on those objects but, when i call the method it is throwing a error as sample() is undefined for the Object. How can i make it work without changing the type of List of Lists(because i want to store objects belonging to different class in a single list of lists)?

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> distributions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
    distributions=[[new NormalDistribution(24,10),new NormalDistribution(100,5)],[new BinomialDistribution(160,0.8)]];
for(int i=0;i<distributions.size();i++){
for(int j=0;j<distributions.get(i).size();j++){
double value = (distributions.get(i).get(j)).sample();//sample() is undefined for the Object    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem:

The `NormalDistribution` and `BinomialDistribution` classes don't have a common superclass that has a `sample()` method.  One is a subtype of `RealDistribution` and the other is a subtype of `IntegerDistribution`.  The respective `sample()` methods return different types; i.e. `double[]` and `int[]` respectively.

So what you need is something like this:

```
    double sample;
    if (distribution instanceof RealDistribution) {
        sample = ((RealDistribution) distribution).sample()[i];
    } else {
        // The int sample value is converted to a double in the assignment.
        sample = ((IntegerDistribution) distribution).sample()[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to type cast your object to the correct class.  In your example `distributions.get(0).get(1)` will give you an object of class `NormalDistribution`. So type cast it to `NormalDistribution`.

```
((NormalDistribution)(distributions.get(0).get(1))).sample()
```

If you don't know the class to type cast at runtime and there is no common interface , try using Java reflection.

```
Object obj = distributions.get(0).get(1)
java.lang.reflect.Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("sample");
double value = method.invoke();
```

Comment: actually i am running that method so it can be either NormalDistribution or BinomialDistribution both implementing different Interfaces. For simplifying i just wrote (distributions.get(0).get(1))).sample();

Comment: @user7117118 Then you can try Java reflection. My answer updated.